# Boeing 747 Autopilot Vertical Speed Function (PID Controller)

Tags: calculus, control-theory

I am working on a Boeing 747 autopilot control system for an at-home flight simulator expansion, and unfortunately my knowledge and understanding of control theory and calculus is a little lacking and I am finding information pertaining to my specific problem difficult to find.

I do not think my question will require you to understand anything about aircraft dynamics, rather, I am simply looking for the mathematical result to a problem I have not been able to figure out.

The 747 autopilot has a vertical speed controller, which allows the pilot to set the rate of climb or descent as measured in feet per minute up or down (however bear in mind that the actual autopilot uses feet per second in that maths). According to the documentation I have on the autopilot, this function uses a proportional component to calculate how much to pitch the airplane up or down, and an integral component to eliminate steady state error.

The proportional control makes sense to me (I think), but the integrator is eluding me. My attempts to write this part of the code have resulted in nothing but uncontrollable oscillations.

In my documentation, it is written like this:

Proportional control:
$\frac {\theta_c}{\Delta \dot h}= 0.09$ $\frac {degree}{ft/sec}$

where:

$\theta_c$ = commanded change of pitch in degrees

$\dot h$ = vertical speed (climb or descent) in feet per second

Integral control

$\frac {(\frac{\theta_c}{\int \Delta \dot h})}{(\frac {\theta_c}{\Delta \dot h})} =0.2$ with the units listed as $\frac {integral}{displacement}$

As I understand it, the proportioner will take the error of vertical speed (delta h dot) and produce 0.09 degrees of pitch change per foot/second of error. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

The integral control however, doesn't make much sense to me. As I understand, an integral controller sums up the error over time to produce an increasing control response to eliminate steady state error. But I do not see how to take the documentation above and turn it into a proper integrator. Unfortunately this is the only documentation I have and it is not beginner friendly and again, correct me if I am wrong.

I have an autopilot in the simulator currently that will accurately deflect the flight controls (in this case, the elevator) to the commanded position (that being the pitch error multiplied by 3.5, then subtracting a damping factor of 2.2 times the current pitch rate). The vertical speed mode mentioned above is meant to calculate how much to change the pitch of the airplane to arrive at the specified rate of climb or descent.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a quite technical question which should be asked in a more engineering-oriented place, rather than a math-oriented place like here.  Try https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/ControlTheory/, you will have more chances.

Comment: Thanks, will do!